# problems with list scope javascript

Tags: javascript

I trying to make a function that tries to access the first item in a list to make a konami code website. The list is defined and then the function is defined to edit the list. This is code

```
<html><body>
<script>
var keys = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
function keyhandler (e) {
    e = e || event;
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    var key = keys[0];
    if (key == e.keyCode) {
        console.log("correct key");
        if (keys.length == 1){
            console.log("konami");
        } else {
            var keys = keys[1,keys.length];
        }
    }
    else {
        var keys = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
    }
}
document.onkeydown = keyhandler;
</script>
</body></html>
```

when I trigger the function by a key-press I get this error :
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined the error is caused by the var key = keys[0] line

Comment: `var keys = keys[1,keys.length];` is not correct javascript, what do you intend it to do?

Comment: It looks idiomatically like trying to get a range of values from an Array. Maybe the slice method was intended here?

Comment: @juvian That's a _valid_ JavaScript statement. There is a _logical_ problem here.

Comment: the problem is with line 7 how do i change it

Comment: @Vohuman yeah meant not correct to slice an array, seemed kind of pythonic looking

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var keys = keys[1,keys.length];
> ```

You've created a new (locally scoped) `keys` variable inside your function and it is masking the one containing the array you are trying to read. Remember: `var` statements are hoisted.

Use different names for those two variables (or if they are *supposed* to be the same variable, remove the `var` statement from the inner one).

---

NB: In JavaScript, `[1,keys.length]` is just a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) it isn't a [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Comment: the line of code needs to remove the first item form the list however this code is not run because it stalls at the defining key

Comment: @AlexanderRD — Yes, for the reasons I described.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing another variable named `keys` inside of your function (`var keys = keys[1, keys.length]`). This shadows the outer variable. Remove the `var` keyword to access the correct variable.

Also, I believe you want to remove the first element from the list. To do so, use [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift).

```
keys.shift();
```

This will modify the array directly so you don't need to assign the result to anything.

Comment: thank you for answer the key.shift but how to i set key to the first item without causing a uncaught type error i trips up at the var key = keys[0]

Comment: @AlexanderRD Like I said, remove `var` before `var keys`.

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin said, hoisting is happening in your function.
Other posters here also said it, you are defining a new local variable in your function.

Let me just show your function with hoisting happening when Javascript interprets your code:

```
var keys = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
function keyhandler (e) {
    // Javascript defines all the local variables at top.
    // This is what hoisting is
    var key;
    var keys;
    e = e || event;
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    // at this point, local variable keys isn't initialized,
    // that's why you are getting the undefined error.
    key = keys[0];
    if (key == e.keyCode) {
        console.log("correct key");
        if (keys.length == 1){
            console.log("konami");
        } else {
            // you are referencing a local variable here
            keys = keys[1,keys.length];
        }
    }
    else {
        // you are referencing a local variable here
        keys = [38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
    }
}
document.onkeydown = keyhandler;
```

As other posters mention, simply removing the var from keys may fix your issue, if that's what intended, but I think it's important to understand what Javascript technically does in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was that

```
var key = keys[0];
```

is not a javascript expression as mentioned in the comment it needed to be replaced with

```
var key = keys.slice(0,2);
```